# Not return anything from filter method?

Tags: javascript

I have a list array:

```
list: [
  {
    id: '3',
    title: 'hi',
  },
  {
    id: '4',
    title: 'there',
  },
],
```

I'm using a method to do some destructuring and return and new array while looking for an item by id

```
  return {
    title: section.title,
    list: [
      ...section.list,
      storeSections[i].list.filter((field) => field.id === ownId)[0],
    ],
  };
```

If it finds it, it will just add it to the new array, for example this object:

```
  {
    id: '3515',
    title: 'hello',
  },
```

But if it doesn't, it will add 'undefined' to the new array, because the filter method will return undefined.

Is there a simple way to change this behavior so that the filter method only adds an item to the array if it finds it?

Comment: This isn't ideal, but I tend to filter the resulting array. Something like `[].filter(Boolean)`

Comment: `[][0]` returns `undefined`

Comment: If you only ever want the first matching element (Since you have `[0]`) have you considered `.find()` instead of `.filter()`?

Comment: @DBS `.find` could result in undefined too

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yep, it's not a solution to the problem, just a possible performance improvement that may/may not be useful to the asker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use spread, when the array is empty you will not get the extra entry.

```js
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [4];
var c = [];

console.log([...a, ...b, ...c])
```

so

```
 return {
    title: section.title,
    list: [
      ...section.list,
      ...storeSections[i].list.filter((field) => field.id === ownId),
    ],
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found is to add:

```
    list: [
      ...section.list,
      storeSections[i].list.filter((field) => field.id === ownId)[0],
    ].filter((item) => item !== undefined),
```

Anothef filter method to remove the undefined values